# Select longest possible integer not preceded by

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to match numbers between 9 and 12 digits long not preceded by 43200-.

`(?<!43200-)([0-9]{9,12})`

So when matching 43200-990003543654, the result is 90003543654 because this is preceded by 43200-9 so this is a match.

This is not what I intended, this should not match.

But I can't seem to figure out how to solve this.

Any help is much appreciated

Thanks,
Glenn

Comment: You could use `(?<!43200-)(?<![0-9])([0-9]{9,12})`, you might also want to add `\b` or `(?![0-9])` in the end to avoid matching numbers with a size larger than 12.

Comment: Can you finish "this should not match" with a "because" clause? This would be clearer if you gave full examples of what is supposed to be matched and what isn't and why.

Comment: Is it required that there always be exactly 5 digits and a dash before the target? If not, please give examples of possible input you want to match

Comment: I think you just need [`(?<!43200-)\b\d{9,12}`](https://regex101.com/r/wK5eI2/1) or [`(?<!43200-)(?<!\d)\d{9,12}`](https://regex101.com/r/nQ8dK7/1)

Comment: Thanks Sebastian and Wiktor, excluding a digit with negative lookahead solved the problem!

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you need a word boundary at the start to prevent false positives, eg `111143200-...`.

You also need word boundary at the end the prevent a match on the first 12 digits of a longer number.

But you mainly need a look behind for 5 digits and a dash

```
(?<!\b43200-)(?<=\b\d{5}-)\d{9,12}\b
```

Or, if no prefix is required, not preceded by a digit

```
(?<!\b43200-)(?<!\d)\d{9,12}\b
```